# Is there a way to increase size of bubble in obiee 12c?

Tags: obiee

Couldn't find a way to increase the default bubble size of a bubble chart in OBIEE 12c. Is it possible to do it or its an restriction in OBIEE?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't touch the charting engine too much. It renders bubbles based on the measures used in the analysis and their values; so it's dynamic and based on the ratios of measure values existing in the analysis.
The minimum size for the ellipsis is about 8 for readability and then it starts to scale up.
VA for example renders things differently using polygons so you'll have a different behaviour there altogether.

Comment: Yes, the bubbles are based on the measure. But the graph which I'm getting is very small due to the dimension I've been using. So I need a way to increase the size manually.

Comment: It's all generated as HTML5 by JS. You can have a go at it if you want but again I strongly recommend you don't. Core JS is html5libloaderutil.js but from there you're on your own :)